# Error when I clicked on the preview button in the developer console , for executing the Lightning Application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

**Hi I got the below error, when I am trying to preview the Lightning Application. I working on the Expense Tracker App . I have followed all the steps to create the Expense Tracker Application **

[image]

When I clicked on the Update preview button, I got below error
Lightning components require My Domain. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

Comment: have you create domain name?In the tutorial it will show you the step how to create domain.

Comment: Rann I can see this question still opened. have you got your ans?

Answer (score 6):

You didn't Deploy domain to the user.

**Steps:**
setup-->Domain management -->my domain

You will find a button **"Deploy to users"**.

Please click the button and then your lightning app will run.

Comment: This suggestion worked.

Answer (score 3):

After winter 16 release. lightning requires domain name to be set.

My Domain must be unique, so you need to pick a name of your own to use for this exercise.

1. From Setup, enter My Domain in the Quick Find box, then select My Domain.
2. Enter the subdomain name you want to use within the sample URL. For example, a company called Universal Containers wants to use the subdomain universalcontainers. The company’s login URL would be https://universalcontainers.my.salesforce.com/. You can use up to 40 characters.
   You can’t use these reserved words for subdomains:

   - www
   - salesforce
   - heroku
     And, you can’t start the domain name with:
   - root
   - status
3. Click Check **Availability**. If your name is already taken, choose a different one.
4. Click Terms and Conditions to review your agreement, then select the checkbox.
5. Click Register Domain.
6. You receive an email when your domain name is ready for testing. (It can take from 30 seconds to 24 hours.)

Source : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_quickstart_my_domain.htm

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a domain.
2. Share it with Users.
3. Click 'Preview' button again.

[follow this link if you need detailed steps](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=domain_name_setup.htm&type=0&language=en_US) on how to activate domain

- Find a unique name and click OK/Save.
- An email will be sent to you when your domain is ready.
- Click and Login to see if it is working

---

Once your domain is ready, make sure that you share the same with users

Set Up> Search for 'My Domain' > 'Share to Users' button

Answer (score 2):

Go to setup menu. Search for "My Domain". Then create a domain for your dev org. That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to setup a domain for Lightning Components. Setup a domain for your org to view Lightning Components.

After setting up your domain, your url will look like

```
https://your-domain.lightning.force.com/c/expenseTracker.app
```

More details about My Domain

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_overview.htm&language=en